# Connecting Pi Video composite to a multicamera-system?

Tags: hardware, camera

I have connected Pi to a [Zmodo multichannel camera system](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16881523062) using a cable from Pi's video composite port to Zmodo Video in. 
I changed the display settings of the Pi to PAL output taking help from [this](https://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/force-raspberry-pi-output-to-composite-video-instead-of-hdmi/03/03/2014/) post. I am output on Zmodo screen but there's a lot of flicker. A Black screen and white flicker.
Do I have to change display settings on Pi to Match it to the Zmodo settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All this settings mentioned in [this](http://bhavyanshu.me/tutorials/force-raspberry-pi-output-to-composite-video-instead-of-hdmi/03/03/2014/)  need to be done plus another line needs to be added. Summarizing below all the lines to be uncommented/added to `/boot/config.txt`

`# uncomment for composite PAL
sdtv_mode =2 # Different modes for NTSC & PAL check which is yours
hdmi_ignore_hotplug = 1
sdtv_aspect = 1`

Also comment(by adding #) the below line

`#hdmi_force_hotplug=1`